# What is the relevant code for getInputStream() in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, xcode, inputstream

In Android Studio, I use this code to get data from server

```
url = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
try
    {
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);

        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        this.header = connection.getHeaderFields();
        this.status = connection.getResponseCode();
    }
```

In Swift 5, I'm able to perform similar task by using `URLSession.shared.dataTask()`, but I couldn't find anything to replace `InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream()`.

After I did some research on Swift 5 inputStream and outputStream, I'm getting more confused, can anyone provide some sample on how to replace this?

Comment: Looking for URLSession?

Comment: I am using URLSession, I have edited my question to be more clear, and I couldn't find anything similar with URLSession.

Answer (score 0):

Use `uploadTask(withStreamedRequest` in order to work with streams https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1410934-uploadtask